# Possible to preview changes done in ASP.NET faster without rebuilding every time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When developing web applications in Visual Studio, for every small changes I make that I want to see it in my browser, I have to press F5 to get VS to compile, and then launch a new browser tab, wait for about 5 seconds (longer when I have database connection) for the page to load before I can preview my change. The compilation done every time before launching the browser seems unnecessary to me and this can take very long for larger applications. I have found this to be very cumbersome and slow.

I'm very used to PHP where I can easily make changes, save the file, return to my browser, hit refresh and I can see the change. It's faster this way because I don't have to wait for VS to rebuild, launch browser, and then for some reason takes a long time to load a page for the first time. Is it possible to have the same kind of flow with C#? At least I don't have to rebuild the whole project every time I want to preview my changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you are changing.

If you change a project used by other projects they will all have to rebuild and there is no way to stop it.

What I would suggest is that you use CTRL + F5 which is start without debugging.  Then you can leave this browser open on this page.  Then if you make a change that requires a rebuild do a rebuild then refresh the browser page.  This will save you the time of launching the browser instance as well as all the overhead of the debugger which needs to load a bunch of stuff.

Comment: i used to right click on project and click view in browser, never tried to know its shortkey...

Comment: And once you've got the site running without debug, you can then attach to the process via visual studio when debugging is needed, and be able to stop debugging without shutting down the site.

Answer (score 4):

In **asp.net mvc** things are a little bit like **php** but not all things, like if you do changes in the **View**, you don't need to recompile your application, but if you do change in **Controller** or **Model** you will surely have to rebuild the project to update the references and the project **dll** that is generated against the **namespace**.

One more thing you don't need to run application in debug mode everytime by pressing F5 you just build and refresh the page, if you really want to debug some error, exception or some logical errors coming in your application business logic then you need to run application in debug mode.

Comment: You may as well add a Visual Studio extension to reload  project whenever it is saved. You can try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserReloadonSave

Answer (score 2):

For asp.net core I use **dotnet watch run** this will automatically see changes you made in files and compile behind the scene.

you can read about it

[dotnet watch run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

[live reloading](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/May/18/Live-Reloading-Server-Side-ASPNET-Core-Apps)